# Difference between depth of market and the limit order book

Tags: trading, terminology, day-trading, limit-order

In trading terminology, is there a difference between "depth of market" (DOM) and the limit order book? I suspect that they are the same because a limit order book shows the "depth" of a market.

When someone says that they are a depth of market trader, does it mean that they trade by looking at limit order books (perhaps in conjunction with Time & Sales [aka the tape])?

Comment: I thought looking at the "depth" (just like in **a sports "depth chart"** for such and such position) was, instead of just noticing that the next order is "100", also noticing that behind that there is a 99, 98, 95 and a 90. A "depth of market" trader is just someone who doesn't understand charting :pppp

Comment: @Fattie "A "depth of market" trader is just someone who doesn't understand charting" — Could you explain? The typical chart does not show the contents of the limit order book.

Comment: Notice it was a joke.  (:pp).  (A) there are various approaches to trading.  For example "fundamentals" "swing" "candlestick!" "astrology" and so on.  (B) "depth of market" is something often mentioned by one particular type of trader, they really look at that and make a decision based on it.  (C) since I'm a "chartist", I was making a joke that anyone who even cares about issues such as "depth of market", is just someone who "doesn't know how to use charting".  OK?  :)